# ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant I18n::RESERVED_KEYS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-i18n

I am running a rails 3 app with ruby 1.9.3. Heroku gives me an error 500 with this message in heroku logs:

> Started GET "/" for 90.3.47.58 at 2014-03-20 08:42:50 +0000
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 176ms

```
<p><%= t('.title_html') %></p>
```

> Rendered store/index.html.erb within layouts/application (96.3ms)

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

> ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant I18n::RESERVED_KEYS):

The app works fine locally.The problem arises only in production deployment.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have to lock your I18n gem at 0.5.0 for now:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/233